# How to implement names for a S3 class?

Tags: r

How can I implement the generic function names for my S3 class so I can "set" the names of my object.

To retrieve the names I simply implemented it as:

```
names.myobject <- function(x, ...){
   x$y
}
```

and then I can do:

```
names(myobject)
```

But I can't use it to set the names in the form of:

```
names(myobject) <- "a"
```

I'm thinking to something like:

```
names.myobject <- function(x, newname){
   x$y <- newnames
}
```

How can implement the "set" form of names?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figure out the signatures of the generics from the functions; the 'setter' is `names<-`.

```
> names
function (x)  .Primitive("names")
> `names<-`
function (x, value)  .Primitive("names<-")
```

`names` and `names<-` are so-called primitive functions, with method dispatch implemented in C, so the usual indication that you're working with an S3 generic (`UseMethod("foo")` in the body of the generic) is not present.

Implement methods following the pattern `generic.class = function...`. Remember that the return value of the setter method needs to be the object that you've updated

```
names.myobject <- function(x) x$y
`names<-.myobject` <- function(x, value) { x$y = value; x }
```

Comment: Thank you Martin. Works as expected.